# Bitwise Operations in Angular Template Expressions

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor

I am creating a component which represents the days of the week. I am trying eastablish whether one of the days has been selected by using bitwise arithmetic (may be this belongs in coding golf?).

However, the Angular compiler complains that the `&` symbol should not be in the template expression. What am I doing wrong? I have tried substituting `&` with `&amp;`, and also have found a couple of questions that deal with this, but for the `|` (OR) operation only.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Angular moaning and groaning]

days-run.componenent.html

```
<div>
  <p>Filter on days run</p>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <td (click)='click(1)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 1'>M</td>
      <td (click)='click(2)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 2'>T</td>
      <td (click)='click(3)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 4'>W</td>
      <td (click)='click(4)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 8'>H</td>
      <td (click)='click(5)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 16'>F</td>
      <td (click)='click(6)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 32'>S</td>
      <td (click)='click(7)' [class.selected]='daysRun & 64'>U</td>
      <td> {{ daysRun }} </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

days-run.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModelService } from './../model/model.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-days-run',
  templateUrl: './days-run.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../controlsCommon.css','./days-run.component.css'],
  providers: [ModelService]
})
export class DaysRunComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  // 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 4 = Weds, 8 = Thurs, 16 = Fri, 32 = Sat, 64 = Sun
  daysRun = 0;

  daysRunString = "MO";

  click(daysRun : number) : void {
    // Toggles bit 0 - 6 using XOR (^) operator
    this.daysRun ^ (Math.pow(2, daysRun - 1));
  }
}
```

Comment: According to [syntax of template expression](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation#syntax),  Angular doesn't support bitwise operator in template expression.

Comment: That'll do it! What a pity. Thank you.

Comment: Make that an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Actually, it does if you put it in () - Ex: `[class.selected]='(daysRun & 64)`

Answer (score 0):

No easy way to work around this, I just declared a hasFlag() function in my component class. I tried to extend Number's prototype to make it work like .NET's but TypeScript doesn't seem to realize the extended functions can be used with enums, plus it's probably a bad idea to mess with built in prototypes anyway.

```
hasFlag(x: number, flag: number): boolean {
  return (x & flag) === flag;
}


<myTag [myAttribute]="hasFlag(myVariable, 1)" />
```

You can alternatively just have it only use the bitwise and if you need to do more math on the result, but this is the common case of using it I think.